# Qt QML. How to have a Flickable whose content bounces against edge but does not exceed it?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I would like to create some sort of visual "bounce against edge" effect for a `Flickable`. But that the edge is a hard edge, like a wall, so that the content cannot be dragged or flicked past it at any time.

Here's some code, where i set `StopAtBounds`, but then i cannot use a rebound transtition.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 800

    Flickable
    {
        anchors.fill: parent

        contentWidth: bob.width
        contentHeight: bob.height

        rightMargin: 200
        leftMargin: 200
        topMargin: 200
        bottomMargin: 200

        // prevents bob from going outside of bounds,
        // but now cant use `rebound` transition.
        // so how to apply `Easing.OutBounce`
        boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds

        Rectangle
        {
            id: bob
            width: 600
            height: 600
            color: "red"
        }
    }
}
```

You can flick the red square and it hits the walls, but it doesn't bounce.

any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think `Flickable` is made for such type of behaviors nor does it support custom behaviors.

Comment: Not yet at least : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-38515

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried
`boundsBehavior: Flickable.OvershootBounds` ?

It gives you that bouncing transition when near borders of flickable. The only thing is that element can slightly go out of limits.

Looks like `Flickable.StopAtBounds` does exactly what it says: stops element at bounds with no rebound animation.

Comment: Yes, but it goes slightly outside. that's my problem. thanks anyway.